# Advanced function define syntax at c++ with ':' after function prototype

Tags: c++, oop, syntax, live555

I'm reading testRTSPClient.cpp at live555 library for read RTSP stream
At a constructor's implementation of DummySink, i meet a strange syntax

```
    DummySink::DummySink(UsageEnvironment& env, MediaSubsession& subsession, char const* streamId)
      : MediaSink(env),
        fSubsession(subsession) {
      fStreamId = strDup(streamId);
      fReceiveBuffer = new u_int8_t[DUMMY_SINK_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    }
```

I don't understand what

```
: MediaSink(env),  
fSubsession(subsession)
```

that after function prototype means, because common function defining syntax is

```
functionName(args)
//without :
{
//implement
}
```

If anyone know about it, please tell me know. Thank you so much

Comment: This is not strange, unusual or advanced syntax. It is very basic syntax for constructors. It should be explained in any introduction to the language.

Comment: _"because common function defining syntax is ..."_ - No, I would say that using the member initializer list is the most common way to initialize base classes and member variables.